# Where is the grave of Prophet Muhammad’s father?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, grave

I would like to know the exact location of where Prophet Muhammad's (Peace and blessings be upon him) father was buried?  Where is his grave?

Answer (score 2):

The tomb of Prophet Muhammad’s father is in Medina.

In the past Abdullah In return of sham trade, went to Medina. In Medina there were some houses belong to bani-alnajar tribe (who were amene's(Abdullah 's wife) relative),Abdullah went to Nabeghe 's house;a person from that tribe. After some Abdullah became sick and died; according to that time custom, they buried him in Nabeghe 's house.

Prophet’s mother and him went to dar-alnabeghe when he was 6 years old and stayed there for 1 month.

Later, Prophet prayed in dar-alnabeghe several times, so they called it dar-alnabeghe mosque.

Some documents:

-Ibn-saad said from Zahri & Ibn-Abas:after hegira to Medina whenever prophet looked at that place,will said:

> «نظر إلي الدار فقال: ههنا نزلت بي أمّي و في هذه الدار قبر أبي عبد
> الله.»

“my mother and me stayed in that place,and there is my father 's grave"(also in that reference: fasl men tarikh almedina from vaghedi)

-Batnuni said:

> «مقام سيّدنا عبدالله والد الرسول... في بيت رجل منهم (بنونجّار) يقال له
> النّابغة

"Grave of Abdullah,prophet 's father,is in Nabeghe 's house,who was from  bani-alnajar tribe"

-kateb Vaghedi said:

> «ودُفِنَ فی دار النابغة وهُوَ رَجلٌ من بنی عدی بن نجّار...»

"He buried in dar-alnabeghe which was house of nabeghe, who was from  bani-alnajar tribe"(tabaghat,volume1)

-ibn-shebh said:

> «قبر عبدالله بن عبدالمطلب فی دارالنابغة»

"Abdullah’s grave exists in dar-alnabeghe"(ibn-shebh 's tarikh-almedina,volume1)

-tabari said:

> «وَدُفن فی دار النابغة فی الدار الصغری إذا دخلت الدار عن یَسارِکَ
> لَیس بین أصحابنا فی ذلک اختلاف»

"And he buried in dar-alnabeghe,in left side which there is no disagreement between our companions about that"(tarikh tabari,volume2)

In 1976 they destroyed this place for Nabavi Mosque Development!

---

Reference in Persian:

- [www.hawzah.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20130108151626/http://www.hawzah.net:80/fa/magazine/magart/4789/5053/44816?ParentID=78191)